# HTML Bullet points to Word XML

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

I need to take user input from a web page and write it to a Word document.

Im using a WYSİWYG Editor that allows bullet points with the output being a html list.

I need to then convert that to Word XML.

Any suggestions?

I have the syntax/structure for the XML bullet lists but I need to convert the html list to the XML bullet point list.

Maybe preg_replace? I'm not 100% how to do that though

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write an actual word document (.docx) then a library like [phpdocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) or [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com) should be able to do that for you.
Alternatively, Word is quite capable of reading HTML files.